# How to configure the "initial working directory" of the Terminal to be by default the same location as the current opened project?

Tags: eclipse

When I open a Terminal in Eclipse, it's by default positioned at

```
$> /home/myUserName>$
```

I'm looking to configure it to be positioned at the same location as the current opened project.

#### Example

- When I open the project "my-project-1" which is located at "/home/userName/path/to/my/personal/projects" then I open the Terminal, it'll be shown as this:

  `$> /home/userName/home/userName/path/to/my/personal/projects/my-project-1>$`
- When I open the project "my-project-2" which is located at "/home/userName/path/to/my/personal/projects" then I open the Terminal, it'll be shown as this:

  `$> /home/userName/home/userName/path/to/my/personal/projects/my-project-2>$`

#### Note:

- I'm using the Oxygen Release (4.7.0).

Answer (score 2):

From the Preferences -> Terminal -> "Local Terminal" configuration screen, you could chose `${project_loc}` as initial working directory.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it should work, but I get this error `Variable references empty selection: ${project_loc}` when that is put in the 'Initial Working Directory' window. Did others get this to work? Am using the PyDev plugin. There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460415).

Comment: it work perfectly for me, is there is a way to make the terminal to use `Git Bash` by default with this variable `${project_loc}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this for "the currently opened project", but you can get close enough by choosing a specific project.
Preferences -> Terminal -> Local Terminal. Select "Variables..."
You then choose `${project_loc}`, then click on "Configure" in the Argument box, start typing your chosen project name, and select it

Comment: Furthermore, if your projects are all located under a common root folder, you can append `/..` to the end of the initial working directory, which makes it the parent folder of the project you selected. For example: `${project_loc:/MyProject}/..`

Comment: There's a UI bug in the Preferences screen, such that after setting a value like in my comment above, when you go back to the preferences page, the value has been corrupted. But it still works.

Answer (score 1):

It's September of 2021, running Eclipse 2021-06 and I still see
"Variable references empty", and I get ../Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS as my initial directory.